# Conversions.ToBoolean vs Convert.ToBoolean

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, performance, profiling

I have been transforming and old VB project into C# one, using [CodeConverter](https://github.com/icsharpcode/CodeConverter). The tool used to transform all the expressions such as:

`CBool(objectUnit.UnitType And HrUnitTypeEnum.CanHaveEmployment)`  into:

`Conversions.ToBoolean(objectUnit.UnitType & HrUnitTypeEnum.CanHaveEmployment)`

where UnitType is of type `HrUnitTypeEnum`.

It is strange to me that it would use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean()` instead of `System.Convert.ToBoolean()`.

At first glance it all looked to work fine, but when I have done memory profiling, there have been repeteadly the cases where the conversion would be exceptionally time consuming:
[image]

Are there any corner cases where those conversions differ?
Should I perform binary operation on enums parsed to integers?

Comment: Are you just trying to write `objectUnit.UnitType.HasFlag(HrUnitTypeEnum.CanHaveEmployment)`?

Comment: As for your question, it seems that `CBool` is compiled to a call to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean` ([SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRIMYHsEBNkA0ANiAG7AEwgCWRBuIA1AD4CSAtgA44zIAEAZQCeyGBHYBYAFAAFOMCLUMfAMJEoyfiul9dfOQqWD5fALIAKAJQ69tgCLV2fKHwCC/AEJYsRaADsbW10XAF5VLx9zACIAFQQ4CCjrKVsAUT9cY2BpdMy1DWQgA)), so when you "convert" the code, it's seeing a method call, rather than `CBool`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar `HasFlag()` isn't the best case for me, because both left and right hand side of the operation can be of compound type. E.g. [528 (512+16) && 24 (16+8)]. Then I would need to find if they have a common bit. 
I do check at the end `(objectUnit.UnitType & HrUnitTypeEnum.CanHaveEmployment) != 0`.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case I think you already have the optimal solution as presented in your latest comment.

Comment: It is highly probable that System.Convert.ToBoolean will work just fine for you. The original VB CBool behavior has addition quirks (surprise, surprise) and the converter is playing it extremely safe by trying to replicate that exactly.

Comment: Sounds like you’ve got your answer which is great but just to add, you *always* need to take converters with a grain of salt and review the output.  Just because it compiles in no way means it right or can’t be improved